# Однородные и неоднородные определения. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая между определениями? 
Нашумевшие (?) непрошеные гости

Answer (score 1):

Диктант "Ночь в Балаклаве"

*В конце́ октября́ дни ещё по-осе́ннему ла́сковые, и Балаклава начина́ет жить своеобра́зной жи́знью. Уезжа́ют после́дние куро́ртники, в тече́ние до́лгого зде́шнего лета наслажда́вшиеся со́лнцем и мо́рем, и сра́зу стано́вится просто́рно, свежо́ и по-дома́шнему делови́то, то́чно по́сле отъе́зда **нашуме́вших непро́шеных госте́й**.*

Как мы видим, **запятая отсутствует.** Определения неоднородные, так как обозначают разные признаки и выражены разными частями речи.

Иногда возможно **сближение признаков** по значению: к примеру,  в данном случае  они раскрывают **общую тему** не особенно приятных для хозяев гостей.

В то же время это предложение **сложное** по своей структуре, содержит **другие однородные члены,** так что  обозначить однородность определений достаточно сложно, даже если бы автор и захотел бы это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, нет. Постановка союза «и» между определениями сомнительна. Нашумевшие гости оказались непрошеными. Смутно присутствует связь между определениями.

Comment: Хотя я бы взглянул на контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна.

Запятая нужна, если присутствует однородность - слова на одном уровне и между ними можно провести параллель.

Например:

*Непрошеные, незваные гости.*

*Хорошие, интересные люди.*

*Полезные, дельные советы.*

*Эффективные, продуманные решения.*

Хорошая проверка однородности - это вставить между определениями союз "и". Здесь он не подходит. То есть запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы запятую не ставил. Не воспринимаю эти определения как однородные.
Но вообще отнесение членов предложения к однородным и неоднородным во многом лежит на совести автора. 
В данном случае надо посмотреть, во-первых, имеется ли в виду одни и те же гости (если о разных, то запятая очевидно нужна), во-вторых, нет ли здесь просто перечисления нежелательных качеств гостей: мало того, что непрошенные, так они еще и шумят. 
И тогда союз "и" вставляется без особых проблем.
Вот как-то так я это вижу.

Comment: @oleedd используйте «править», чтобы улучшить ответ; комментарии при этом оставлять не обязательно.